# On a mistake in calculating $\int_0^{2\pi} \cot (x + ib) \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cot(x+ib)\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(x+ib)}{\sin(x+ib)}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{i(e^{ix-b}+e^{-ix+b})}{(e^{ix-b}-e^{-ix+b})}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{\left | z \right |=1}\frac{(ze^{-b}+\frac1ze^{b})}{(z^2e^{-b}-e^{b})}\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\int_{\left | z \right |=1}\frac{(z^2e^{-b}+e^{b})}{(z^3e^{-b}-ze^{b})}\mathrm{d}z\\
&=2\pi iRes_{z=0} \frac{(z^2e^{-b}+e^{b})}{(z^3e^{-b}-ze^{b})} \\
&=-2\pi i\\
\end{align}
$$

but I know from my book that

[image]

Comment: What if $\,z=\pm e^b\;$? These can be poles...and for sure there's one unless $\,b=0\;$ , but then the function is real.

Comment: How do you "know" that $\int_0^{2\pi} \cot(x+ib)\,dx = -2\pi i \sin b$? Maple doesn't agree with this.

Comment: @DonAntonio That was my first thought too, but it doesn't help, the residue at $\pm e^b$ is $1$, so if $|e^b| < 1$ we still don't get the proposed formula.

Comment: I know, @mrf...but still that result looks fishy...

Comment: @mrf from the book which Iam study from it

Comment: I think the computation is correct for $b > 0$, i.e. that the integral is $-2\pi i$. For $b < 0$ I get $2\pi i$.

Comment: @DonAntonio the book give me that b>0

Comment: A local primitive of $\cot (x + ib)$ is a branch of $\log (\sin (x+ib))$ (plus a constant). The value of $\sin (x+ib)$ winds around $0$ once when $x$ increases from $0$ to $2\pi$, with negative orientation if $b > 0$, positive orientation if $b < 0$. So the value of the integral is $\pm 2\pi i$, as @mrf said.

Comment: Aaaah, did it perhaps say the value is $-2\pi i \cdot \operatorname{sign} b$? Okay, I see the book says $\sin$, not $\operatorname{sign}$. Perhaps a typo.

Comment: so the mistake in my book not in my solution

Comment: That seems pretty reasonable: either a typo o misreading $\;\sin b\;$ instead of  sign$\,b\;$ ...

Comment: Well, if $b > 0$. for $b < 0$, you have the two poles $\pm e^b$ in the unit disk, and you get the residues $1+1+(-1)$ and the integral $2\pi i$.